# Building string add double quote between two variables

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation, double-quotes

I have been looking at this for a while trying everything I can find on SO.  There are many posts but I must be missing something.

I am building a string and need to get a double quote in it between two variables.

I want the string to be

> convert -density 150 "L:\03 Supervisors\

The code is

```
tw.WriteLine(strPrefix + " " + strLastPath);
```

where

```
strPrefix = convert -density 150
```

and

```
strLastPath = L:\\03 Supervisors\
```

I have tried many combinations of "" """ """" \" "\ in the middle where the space is being inserted.

Please show me what I am missing.

Comment: So you want to concatenate `strPrefix` with `strLastPath` but add a `"` in the middle?

Comment: Yes sir.  I am adding a space and need the double quote after the space next to the strLastPath value.

Comment: @MatthewD you could have found this by doing a simple google search for example open up a new browser and type the following in the search 
`C# stackoverflow add double quotes around a string variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample console application that achieves what you're after:

```
namespace DoubleQuote
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strPrefix = "convert - density 150";
            var strLastPath = @"L:\\03 Supervisors\";

            Console.WriteLine(strPrefix + " \"" + strLastPath);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If written as a format string it would look like this:

```
var textToOutput = string.Format("{0} \"{1}", strPrefix, strLastPath);
Console.WriteLine(textToOutput);
```

Comment: I know I've tried that but let me give it a try

Comment: If you've tried it then either I've missed the point of what you're trying to achieve, or you tried it wrong .... as I have a console window open right now showing the text you're expecting to see! =)

Comment: That is it. Man I know i tried that.

Comment: You know what it is, I am seeing the \" in the immediate windows but when the sting is written it doesn't come out.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

```
var output1 = strPrefix + "\"" + strLastPath;
```

Or using a verbatim string:

```
var output2 = strPrefix + @"""" + strLastPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
     var strPrefix = "convert -density 150";

        var strLastPath = @"L:\03 Supervisors\";

        Console.WriteLine(strPrefix + " " + '"'+strLastPath);
```